# How do I profile and improve configuration for this complex aggregate / left join query with many results and temp tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been plagued for a long time with an extremely slow query with an aggregate on a table which has 138m rows (8 GB, 17GB with indexes). The query currently takes between 20-300 seconds. For various reasons (minimal control over the application) I can't really change the way the queries are generated, so I have to deal with them as they currently are. I can, however, fiddle with indexes, some field type changes (as long as it doesn't break the application) and mysqld configuration changes.

(However, for the sake of argument and education, I'm happy to hear about any query changes too.)

This is one example of the basic template of these queries:

```
SELECT ( Sum(`export_value`) ) AS `val`,
       ( name_en )             AS `name`,
       `new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy`.`year`,
       `new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy`.`destination_id`,
       `new_observatory_country`.`name_3char`,
       `new_observatory_country`.`region_id`,
       `new_observatory_country`.`continent`
FROM   `new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `new_observatory_country`
                    ON ( `new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy`.`destination_id` =
                         `new_observatory_country`.`id`
                       )
WHERE  `new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy`.`origin_id` = 223
GROUP  BY `year`,
          `destination_id`
HAVING Sum(`export_value`) > 0
```

The predicate might change slightly (different `origin_id`, or `destination_id`, etc) or the sum field might be different (e.g. `import_value` or `export_value - import_value`, but this is the basic gist and I'm happy if we can get a gain even on just this one.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED on the query gives a depressing query plan:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy
         type: ref
possible_keys: origin_product,origin_destination
          key: origin_product
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 7467534
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: new_observatory_country
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: atlas.new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy.destination_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra:
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Here the `Using temporary; Using filesort` is concerning. The queries are also expected to return a lot of rows - around 10000 wouldn't be surprising, though often only a few thousand. But to get those, it must aggregate over much more.

SHOW CREATE TABLE output:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `origin_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `destination_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `export_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `origin_product` (`origin_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `origin_destination` (`origin_id`,`destination_id`),
  KEY `year` (`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=156586307 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `new_observatory_country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `name_numeric` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_2char` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_3char` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `continent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capital_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `coordinates` longtext,
  `name_ar` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_de` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_el` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_es` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_fr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_he` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_hi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_it` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ja` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ko` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_nl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ru` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_pt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_tr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_zh_cn` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originally_included` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `observatory_country_f6a8b032` (`region_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=346 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Some variables:

```
mysql> show global status like '%uptime%';
+---------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name             | Value |
+---------------------------+-------+
| Uptime                    | 19749 |
| Uptime_since_flush_status | 19749 |
+---------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global status like '%tmp%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 23      |
| Created_tmp_files       | 6       |
| Created_tmp_tables      | 3060    |
| Handler_tmp_update      | 8115681 |
| Handler_tmp_write       | 72580   |
| Rows_tmp_read           | 8154427 |
+-------------------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%innodb_buffer_pool_size%';
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name           | Value       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 12465471488 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Observations:

- When I run the same query twice back to back it doesn't seem to speed up, which tells me that the innodb buffer pool isn't really helping much - probably thrashing quite a bit, though this is me speculating. "Warming" the cache by running the query over and over many times seems to drop it to about 1/3rd, though this isn't very realistic of a scenario.
- We won't have any writes to this table, so I'm willing to give up anything in that regard.
- Part of the issue seems to be that indexes don't seem to narrow this query down enough, since it already returns a ton of rows, aggregated from even more rows. I wonder if I should just get rid of the compound indices altogether to save on memory that could be used for something else - more buffer pool? Or perhaps I could switch to something like just a simple origin_id, destination_id index, which might perform similarly and take up way less RAM.

Things I tried:

- Getting more RAM: I now have an m4.xlarge on RDS (16GB ram) - a moderate improvement from 4GB, but didn't fix the issue. I imagine if I can fit the entire working set into memory, it could be better. I could try to go even larger in a bid to experiment, but it's becoming wasteful and cost-prohibitive for a server that doesn't get much traffic.
- Increasing `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` to 1gb - I know this is too large since this is per connection, but I was curious, and regardless the improvement seems nil. Then I realized running the query doesn't seem to change `created_tmp_disk_tables` so that's probably why.

Things I can think of:

- Try to reduce the sizes of the tables by using more efficient variables (SMALLINT for origin_id, destination_id, product_id; compress name fields to be fixed length) to save space and load more of the working set in memory.
- Change the table to use a natural primary/clustered index rather than a surrogate: `origin_id, destination_id, product_id, year`, but I'm worried this is going to bias towards queries by origin_id but make the destination_id queries worse, for example.

Mostly, I'm at a loss as to how to further diagnose and narrow down the issue. The query plan doesn't seem to be very detailed, and there seems to be no way in mysql to get some sort of detailed trace of how many seconds each portion of the query is taking, whether I'm overflowing any buffers, etc. What else should I try?

Comment: @philipxy export values can't be negative. origin_id / destination_id could be FK'd to new_observatory_country.id, though in practice we don't really need the FK constraint because we already control the generation of data (it's guaranteed to be well-formed) and bulk-load it once.

Comment: The DBMS can optimize queries when it knows the data is limited in form! Declare all relevant CKs (candidate keys) (eg natural keys)--ie PK & UNIQUE NOT NULL. Declare all relevant FKs--and that means for any CK target not just PK. For x non-negative sum(x) > 0 is exists x > 0 and for x positive sum(x) > 0 is exists x. Way faster than group/sum! (In general calculating sum only when you need to may be faster but re-grouping may make things slower. But here you are joining before group anyway so can test the inequality in the join.) PS  Tell us *all* restrictions on your data.

Comment: PS Do you understand KEY is non-standard and maybe not so clear? "KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems." With a slow query be sure you read about indexes & optimization in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

My first try would be to aggregate before joining:

```
select
  s.val,
  s.year,
  c.name_en,
  s.destination_id,
  c.name_3char,
  c.region_id,
  c.continent
from
(
  select 
    year,
    destination_id,
    sum(export_value) as val
  from new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy
  where origin_id = 223
  group by year, destination_id
  having sum(export_value) > 0 
) s
left join new_observatory_country c on c.id = s.destination_id;
```

(I hope `name_en` does reside in `new_observatory_country`. Your query makes it look thus, but I cannot be sure.)

The optimal index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX idxs ON
  new_observatory_sitc4_ccpy (origin_id, destination_id, year, export_value, import_value);
```

The index starts with `origin_id` from the `WHERE` clause, so records get easily found. It continues with the `destination_id` and `year` from the `GROUP BY` clause to ease aggregation. I placed `destination_id` before `year`, because this is used for the join, but I don't know whether this really makes any difference. At last I include the other columns used, which is `export_value` here and `import_value` in similar queries. This makes this a covering index (all columns used in the query are in the index), so reading the index alone suffices and the table doesn't have to be read.

As for `new_observatory_country`: we access this table via its primary key, so no further index is necessary. We can, however, provide a covering index, too. It starts with `id`, because this is the column we use for finding records for the join.

```
CREATE INDEX idxc ON 
  new_observatory_country (id, name_3char, region_id, continent, name_en);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your well-thought-out response! After very brief initial experimentation it does appear that the subquery does quite a bit better than the join! Though as I mention in the question, unfortunately I'm still stuck with the query the software generates. You're right about name_en, by the way.

Comment: Re: the covering index - I understand that in the case of a table with many columns, a covering index is helpful since it creates a smaller, sorted data structure that can be scanned quickly, but since your suggested index for the ccpy table contains pretty much all of the columns in the table, wouldn't it be better to just change the primary key at that point?

Comment: No, don't change the PK. The primary key is what uniquely identifies a record. You chose an ID and that's fine. (Though I am surprised that there is no additional unique key in the table. Well, some rare times it is like that, though.) In an index the order matters. You can reduce the index by removing columns from the right, hence. But with each field you remove, the index becomes less helpful of course.

Comment: ThorstenKettner & @MaliAkmanalp The question mention of "natural key" & a comment to me re FKs suggests that there is a natural CK.

Comment: Right - the natural (and unique) key would be: `origin_id, destination_id, product_id, year`

Comment: Well, whether primary or not, you should have a unique constraint on these columns! That would create an index, and you could order its columns `origin_id, destination_id, year, product_id`. Not as good as a covering index of course, but still second best.